# selecting parent node jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following html:

```
<div class="parent1">
    <div class="child1">
        <div class="child2"><img /></div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

and the following javascript:

```
$(".child2 img").bind(
    "click",
    function ()
    {
        $(this).addClass("enabled");
    }
);
```

This currently adds the "enabled" class to the image tag in the child2 div but I want to add the "enabled" class to the parent1 div.

Any idea?

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com

Comment: not quite specific enough...

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using that you're (still) using `bind()`?

Comment: @ScottJoudry Read the whole thing. You'll be a lot better off in the long run.

Comment: @DavidThomas I'm using bind because I'm binding to click and touchend...I ommitted touchend to simplify the question.

Comment: My point was the [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) has been *replaced* (by [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) in more recent versions of jQuery (1.7+), which also allows for multiple events to be delegated.

Comment: version 1.5 is what I am using. It's Drupal with jQuery Update module installed but I need that version for another feature.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is being closed? If you want me to ask better questions please tell me what I did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".child2 img").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".parent1").addClass("enabled");
});
```

`.closest` traverses up through the DOM tree and finds matching element.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by using [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
$(".child2 img").click(function(){
    $(this).parents(".parent1").addClass("enabled");
});
```

The significant difference between `closest()` and `parents()` is closest starts traversing from the current element *i.e] the image tag*. At the same time parents starts traversing from its immediate parent *i.e] from the div with class child2*.

---

### [DEMONSTRATION](http://jsfiddle.net/TAA2R/)